# how to use captcha ajax php and validation together? When i submit the form it must not refresh

Tags: php, ajax, captcha

i start with form tag the add name age phonenumber resume input boxes and a captcha but not able to send the form by ajax to a php file which will mail. when i send the mail the screen refreshes**

```
 <form action="#" name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM">
          <label>Name</label>
**then i put other labels**
          <input name="name" size="30" type="text" id="name">
          <br clear="all" />
          <label>Email</label>
          <input name="email" size="30" type="text" id="email">
          <br clear="all" />
          <div id="wrap" align="center">
            <img src="get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
            <br clear="all" />
            <input name="code" type="text" id="code">
          </div>
          <img src="refresh.jpg" width="25" alt="" id="refresh" />
          <label>&nbsp;</label>
          <input value="Send" type="submit" id="Send">
        </form>
```

Comment: <form action="#" name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input name="name" size="30" type="text" id="name">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input name="email" size="30" type="text" id="email">
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="wrap" align="center">
        <img src="get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
        <br clear="all" />
        <input name="code" type="text" id="code">
      </div>
      <img src="refresh.jpg" width="25" alt="" id="refresh" />
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <input value="Send" type="submit" id="Send">
    </form>

Comment: What is the code you are using to send to php , can you paste the JavaScript code here

Comment: If you want to do it with ajax then you just need to add an jQuery click event to the submit button or submit event to the form, then in that function use the ajax (see answer aravind) to send the form data. Then use the success or error (return false to end the submit) functions to give feedbackto the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SESSION in the file get_captcha.php to store the value of the captcha code and when you submit the code the match the post value of the captcha code entered by the user to the value saved in the SESSION .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for ajax form submit

```
 $.ajax({  
  type:'POST', 
  url: 'yourphpfile.php', 
  data:$('#formid').serialize(), 
  success: function(response) 
  {
     // do what ever you want with the repose 
  }
});
```

in your php file you specify the validation for the captcha by comparing the captcha value generated and stored in the session . if the captcha fails display the error using javascript based on the response you get